# simstudy: genData producing identical values

Tags: r, package, simulation

This is my first attempt at simulating data - we'd like to simulate a dataset and have elected to use simstudy using the following code:

```
def <- defData(varname='median_household_income',formula=mean(
               df$median_household_income))
def <- defData(def, varname='share_unemployed_seasonal',formula=mean(
               df$share_unemployed_seasonal))
def <- defData(def, varname='share_population_in_metro_areas',
               formula=mean(df$share_population_in_metro_areas))
def <- defData(def, varname='share_population_with_high_school_degree',
               formula=mean(df$share_population_with_high_school_degree))
def <- defData(def, varname='share_non_citizen',
               formula=mean(df$share_non_citizen))
def <- defData(def, varname='share_white_poverty',
               formula=mean(df$share_white_poverty))
def <- defData(def, varname='gini_index',formula=mean(df$gini_index))
def <- defData(def, varname='share_non_white',formula=mean(df$share_non_white))
def <- defData(def, varname='share_voters_voted_trump',
               formula=mean(df$share_voters_voted_trump))
#outcome
def <- defData(def, varname='avg_hatecrimes_per_100k_fbi',formula=
               ".0001*median_household_income + 44*share_unemployed_seasonal + 
               -2.8*share_population_in_metro_areas +
               24*share_population_with_high_school_degree + 22*share_non_citizen + 
               3.2*share_white_poverty + 55*gini_index + -4*share_non_white + 
               -2.6*share_voters_voted_trump")

#generate simulated data
df_sim <- genData(10000,def)
```

The output looks like this:

```
 head(df_sim)
 id median_household_income share_unemployed_seasonal share_population_in_metro_areas
1:  1                55223.61                0.04956863                       0.7501961
2:  2                55223.61                0.04956863                       0.7501961
3:  3                55223.61                0.04956863                       0.7501961
4:  4                55223.61                0.04956863                       0.7501961
5:  5                55223.61                0.04956863                       0.7501961
6:  6                55223.61                0.04956863                       0.7501961
```

Why are all the generated values identicl? My understanding is that the variables are generated according to a normal distribution by default. Any help with this is appreciated!

Comment: It would be helpful if you specified where do the functions defData and genData come from.

Comment: In general, it is good to follow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that you are referring to a package `simstudy`. If you check the documentation for `defData` function ([link here](https://rdrr.io/cran/simstudy/man/defData.html)), you will find out that there is `variance` parameter to the `defData` function which defaults to zero. If you want to have non-identical observations, you need to set this value to a number larger than 0.

The default behavior of `defData` function:

```
defData(dtDefs = NULL, varname, formula, variance = 0,
  dist = "normal", link = "identity", id = "id")
```

So you might want to run a command like

```
def <- defData(varname='median_household_income',
               formula=mean(df$median_household_income),
               variance = 1)
```